# Angular2 LazyLoading with ngx-quicklink not working

Tags: angular

oh no, i'm so stupid. I found the error and it is in a completely different place and is rarely stupid. We have a separate routing file for the test with mock data and I forgot to include it there.

---

We have a project in which only the modules that are linked on the overview page (are different for each user) should be loaded in the background. That's how I came across ngx-quicklink. After the installation according to the description, but now I get only the following error:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken LinkHandler -> [object Object] -> RouterPreloader -> PreloadingStrategy -> PreloadingStrategy -> PreloadingStrategy]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for PreloadingStrategy!
    at NullInjector.get (core.mjs:7493:27)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7914:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:618:33)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (core.mjs:622:60)
    at Object.RouterPreloader_Factory [as factory] (router.mjs:443:99)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (core.mjs:8015:35)
    at R3Injector.get (core.mjs:7903:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (core.mjs:618:33)
```

Here my files:
**app.module.ts**

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { APP_INITIALIZER, CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/form-field';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { TranslateLoader, TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from 'src/app/app.component';
import { ProjectModule } from 'src/app/project/project.module';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';
import localeDeExtra from '@angular/common/locales/extra/de';
import { ApiModule } from 'build/openapi';
import { DesignService } from './shared/services/design/design.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { concatMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { OpenapiCastService } from './shared/services/OpenApiCast/openapi-cast-filter.service';
import { JsonHelpersService } from './shared/services/helpers/json-helpers.service';
import { AuthGuard } from './shared/services/Authorisation/auth/auth.guard';

registerLocaleData(localeDe, 'de-DE', localeDeExtra);


function initializeAppFactory(sDesign: DesignService): () => Observable<boolean> {
   return () => sDesign.sOpenapi.checkConnection().pipe(
      concatMap(value => sDesign.loadDesignData( -1 ))
   ); 
}

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      ProjectModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot({
         loader: {
            provide: TranslateLoader,
            useClass: DesignService,
            deps: [OpenapiCastService, JsonHelpersService],
         },
      }),
      ApiModule
   ],
   providers: [
      Location,
      AuthGuard,
      {
         provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
         useFactory: initializeAppFactory,
         deps: [DesignService],
         multi: true
      },
      { provide: MAT_FORM_FIELD_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, useValue: {floatLabel: 'always'}},
      { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy },
   ],
   exports: [
      TranslateModule
   ],
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MaintenanceWorkComponent } from './shared/pages/maintenance-work/maintenance-work.component';
import { NotFoundPageComponent } from './shared/pages/not-found-page/not-found-page.component';
import { ROUTESURL, URL_PARAMS } from './shared/shared.model';
import { LoginComponent } from './shared/pages/login/login.component';
import { OverviewComponent } from './project/base/pages/overview/overview.component';
import { QuicklinkModule, QuicklinkStrategy } from 'ngx-quicklink';

export const routes: Routes = [
   {
      path: 'm1',
      loadChildren: () => import('../app/project/M1/m1.module').then(m => m.M1Module)
   },
   {
      path: 'm2',
      loadChildren: () => import('../app/project/M2/m2.module').then(m => m.M2Module)
   },
   {
      path: '',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: ROUTESURL.LOGIN
   },
   {
      path: ":" + URL_PARAMS.TARGETGROUP + "/:" + URL_PARAMS.LOGIN ,
      component: LoginComponent,
   }, 
   {
      path: ROUTESURL.OVERVIEW,
      component: OverviewComponent,
   }, 
   {
      path: ROUTESURL.MAINTENANCEWORK,
      component: MaintenanceWorkComponent,
   }, 
   {
      path: ROUTESURL.NOTFOUND,
      component: NotFoundPageComponent
   },
   {
      path: '**',
      pathMatch: 'full',
      redirectTo: ROUTESURL.NOTFOUND
   }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
   RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {preloadingStrategy: QuicklinkStrategy})
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**shared-module.ts**

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MaterialModule } from '../material/material.module';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { MaintenanceWorkComponent } from './pages/maintenance-work/maintenance-work.component';
import { NotFoundPageComponent } from './pages/not-found-page/not-found-page.component';
import { SpinnerComponent } from './components/spinner/spinner.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';
import { BlankComponent } from './components/blank/blank.component';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './pages/login/login.component';
import { QuicklinkModule } from 'ngx-quicklink';


@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      HeaderComponent,
      FooterComponent,
      MaintenanceWorkComponent,
      NotFoundPageComponent,
      SpinnerComponent,
      BlankComponent,
      LoginComponent,
   ],
   imports: [
      CommonModule,
      MaterialModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot(),
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      RouterModule,
      QuicklinkModule
   ],
   providers: [

   ],
   exports: [
      MaterialModule,
      HeaderComponent,
      FooterComponent,
      TranslateModule,
      MaintenanceWorkComponent,
      NotFoundPageComponent,
      SpinnerComponent,
      BlankComponent,
      QuicklinkModule
   ],  
   schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

**project.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from '../shared/shared.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { OverviewComponent } from './base/pages/overview/overview.component';
import { OverviewTileComponent } from './base/components/overview-tile/overview-tile.component';

@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      OverviewComponent,
      OverviewTileComponent
  ],
   imports: [
      CommonModule,
      SharedModule,
      FormsModule,
      ReactiveFormsModule,
      TranslateModule.forRoot(),
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
   ],
   exports: [
      SharedModule
   ],
   providers: [
      DatePipe
   ]
})
export class ProjectModule { }
```

**m1.module.ts**

```
import { CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import { SharedModule } from 'src/app/shared/shared.module';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { M1RoutingModule } from './m1-routing.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  ],
  imports: [
   CommonModule,
   SharedModule,
   FormsModule,
   TranslateModule.forChild({
      extend: true
    }),
   ReactiveFormsModule,
   M1RoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [
     DatePipe
  ],
  exports: [
     TranslateModule
  ],
  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA]
})
export class M1Module { }
```

**m1-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { M1URL } from './m1.model';
import { NotFoundPageComponent } from 'src/app/shared/pages/not-found-page/not-found-page.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: NotFoundPageComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class M1RoutingModule { }
```

m2 is like m1

**overview.component.html**

```
<div class="page-wrapper" *ngIf="(done$ | async)">
   <ng-container *ngIf="noModule">
      <h3 [innerHTML]="'project.pages.overview.no-module' | translate"></h3>
   </ng-container>
   <ng-container *ngIf="!noModule">
      <app-overview-tile *ngFor="let module of moduleList" [module]="module"></app-overview-tile>
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

**overview-tile.component.html**

```
<mat-card data-testId="translate">
   <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title color="primary">
         <div data-testId="title">{{module.title}}</div>
      </mat-card-title>
      <mat-card-subtitle>
         <div data-testId="subtitle">{{module.subTitle}}</div>
      </mat-card-subtitle>
   </mat-card-header>
   <img mat-card-image [src]="module.imgLink">
   <mat-card-content data-testId="description">
      {{module.description}}
   </mat-card-content>
   <mat-card-actions >
      <div class="tileRow">
         <a routerLink="/m1" routerLinkActive="active">
            <button mat-raised-button color="primary" data-testId="button">
               <span translate>translate.project.components.project-tile.button</span>
            </button>
         </a>
      </div>
   </mat-card-actions>
</mat-card>
```

Comment: better create stackblitz

Comment: i tried but stackbliz hangs when installing the dependencies

Comment: oh no, i'm so stupid. I found the error and it is in a completely different place and is rarely stupid. We have a separate routing file for the test with mock data and I forgot to include it there.